# Improving Performance of Rendering 2D Tiled Terrain

Tags: java, lwjgl

Hello everyone Ive been working on optimizing my rendering technique for my 2D game. Right now I render quads in the most modern way I can find using VAO for my vertices and then indices my rendering looks like this:

```
public void render(Map<TexturedModel,List<Entity>> entities)
{
    for(TexturedModel model : entities.keySet())
    {
        if(model!= null)
        {
            prepareTexturedModel(model);
            List<Entity> batch = entities.get(model);
            for(Entity entity : batch)
            {
                prepareInstance(entity);
                GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,model.getRawModel().getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
            }
            unbindTexturedModel();
        }
    }
}
```

PrepareTexturedModel(model) simply binds a texture to the quad, prepareInstance(entity) simply sets transformation matrix and other attributes of the entity to be drawn. Currently the game Im making creates 2D terrain using Simplex Noise and creates a new Quad of width 16 and height 16 and ONLY the quads on screen are rendered so depending on the size of the screen more or less quads will be rendered, which increases or decreases performance respectively.

[image: Tile Border Image]

The image above should show how tiles are separated, the water doesnt show a border because its a collection of 32x32 quads instead of 16x16, just to make the texture look bigger.

My main question is how could I go about optimizing the rendering of those tiles, also just a side not they dont have to be individually editable, one idea I was thinking about was grouping similar tiles together and just making one larger tile and then texturing that, which would decrease the number of vertices but I im stumped on how I could go about doing that as well.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Ok thanks I just wasnt sure if grouping similar quads together could cause some problems later on, it will also greatly increase the CPU usage when generating terrain since I would need to figure out how many quads were together then group them all into one bigger quad

Comment: @httpdigest the issue also is that I calculate lighting based on the vertices as well, so would I simply calculate "fake" vertices and pass those through the vertex/fragment shader?

Comment: @httpdigest I think overall it would just take far to much work to search through all the tiles and group them how I would need to group them into to make that work while still keeping the same(if not greater) level of detail around the edges.

Comment: @httpdigest Or could I just use my terrain generation to create a vertex array of the outermost points of the object, then layer a repeated ground texture over that whole object, then I would have a lot of vertices but they would all be on the outer edge instead of having a ton of vertices that dont do much like my current version

Comment: @httpdigest Just today I implemented instance rendering, since every object I draw is a quad and it has down essentially nothing to improve FPS so not sure what else to do